# Scope problems with nested java loops

Tags: java, for-loop, scope, processing, nested

I'm learning processing (for those who don't know its a java-based language geared towards visual arts), and I've come across a strange problem with nested for loops.
This is a simple program that (should) generate a random number of points, and connect them all.

```
size(1280, 1050);
background(227, 199, 147);
smooth();
stroke(255);
strokeWeight(2);

int points = int(random(30)) + 2;
int[][] Points  = new int[points][2];

for (int i = 0; i < points; i++)
 {
       Points[i][0] = int(random(1280));
   Points[i][1] = int(random(1050));
 }

for (int i = 0; i + 1 < points; i++)
{
  for (int L = i+1; L < points; L++);
  {
    line(Points[i][0], Points[i][1], Points[L][0], Points[L][1]);
  }
}
```

When I run this I get an error saying 'cannot find anything named L', which seems insane to me. Any ideas?

Comment: This is unrelated to your problem, but might trip you up later on. In pure Java you shouldn't have variables whose names start with a capital letter. So in this example your array 'Points' and your loop counter 'L' would both be invalid. they should be 'points' and 'l'. And as a rule you should not have two variable names that only differ by capitalisation (ie. you shouldn't have both "Points" and "points" as variables in the same program). This is almost guaranteed to produce bugs that are hard to track down.

Comment: In fact, the compiler should be spouting off warnings to that effect. Heed those warnings, they'll make your life easier.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have a semicolon after the nested loop. This makes a syntactically correct empty loop, followed by a block that references an undeclared variable `L`.

As a side note, it is typical to name loop variables with lowercase letters, typically starting in `i`, `j`, `k`, `m`, and and so on. Lowercase `l` is often skipped due to its similarity to uppercase `I`.

Answer (score 1):

You have a semi-colon after the for loop declaration:

```
for (int L = i+1; L < points; L++);
```

Comment: Too slow! Oh well. At least I can try to be useful by adding that it is generally considered bad form when writing Java to use variable names that start with (or in this case *is*) a capital letter.